# While making header fixed in DataTable it will not work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a fixed header for a DataTable. It works fine when the data is in the same file where I have included all script files. The problem is, when I implement the same thing in those files where the data is coming from the other file, it will not work.

Example: I have one form which contains a dropdown, and when I change the drop down it will call another php file from which the DataTable comes. In this case the problem is there.

I have already included links to all JavaScript files in the form, and the code I have tried is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);
});
```

I think in the second get data file I am not able to get that javascript file. Please help.